# Commodore BASIC: why was the PET's GOTO so slow?

Tags: basic, 6502, commodore, benchmarking

Received wisdom has it that Commodore didn't want to pay Microsoft extra for updated BASIC interpreters, and thus very little changed in Commodore BASIC v2 from the PETs to the C64. But consider the following program:

```
5 PRINT
10 PRINT "FOR:"
20 T=TIME
30 FOR I=1 TO 7138
40 NEXT I
50 DT=(TIME-T)/60
60 PRINT I;"LOOPS IN";DT;"S:";INT(I/DT);"/S"
70 PRINT "GOTO:"
80 T=TIME
90 FOR I=1 TO 4588
100 GOTO 110
110 NEXT I
120 DT=(TIME-T)/60
130 PRINT I;"LOOPS IN";DT;"S:";INT(I/DT);"/S"
135 PRINT
```

Run on an NTSC C64, it outputs:

```
FOR:
 7139 LOOPS IN 10 S: 713 /S
GOTO:
 4589 LOOPS IN 10 S: 458 /S
```

But on a PET (almost any model), the results are:

```
FOR:
 7139 LOOPS IN 9.93333334 S: 718 /S
GOTO:
 4589 LOOPS IN 13.3166667 S: 344 /S
```

So while the `FOR` loops run about the same speed on both machines, the PET's `GOTO` is roughly ⅓ slower than the C64's.

So my question: what changed in the code to improve this performance? (And perhaps a secondary question: was this improvement made by Microsoft and reflected in other MS 6502 interpreters?)

---

Further to [WimC's comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17314/commodore-basic-why-was-the-pets-goto-so-slow?noredirect=1#comment58929_17314) I renumbered the test as suggested to ensure that the high byte of the `GOTO` target was higher than that of the current line:

```
5 PRINT
10 PRINT "FOR:"
20 T=TIME
30 FOR I=1 TO 7138
40 NEXT I
50 DT=(TIME-T)/60
60 PRINT I;"LOOPS IN";DT;"S:";INT(I/DT);"/S"
70 PRINT "GOTO:"
80 T=TIME
90 FOR I=1 TO 4588
100 GOTO 310
310 NEXT I
320 DT=(TIME-T)/60
330 PRINT I;"LOOPS IN";DT;"S:";INT(I/DT);"/S"
335 PRINT
```

The C64 results stay the same, but on an emulated PET the `GOTO` rate is faster:

```
FOR:
 7139 LOOPS IN 9.93333334 S: 718 /S
GOTO:
 4589 LOOPS IN 9.95 S: 461 /S
```

Comment: Interesting. The faster FOR execution is quite in line with expectation due the higher clock rate. (BTW, it's just TI)

Comment: I know I could've just used `TI`, but I like my code legible. Anyone who wants BASIC to be efficient is missing the point.

Comment: True, still, my point would be rather to have clean/portable code. Superfluous characters in function names are not exactly helpful. Not to mention that it doesn't work with TI$

Comment: Similar `TIME` variables exist in Locomotive BASIC (300 Hz) and BBC BASIC (100 Hz). This code is a small subset of code I need to run on as many platforms as possible. If I'd just written `TI` it wouldn't have run on these other platforms and its purpose wouldn't be clear to those of us who didn't start with C= BASIC. So clean, portable is what this is.

Comment: PET basic v2 only starts scanning from the current line if the high byte of the goto line number is greater than the high byte of the current line number. Otherwise it starts at the beginning of the program. What happens if you renumber lines 110 up so that they start from 310 (and the goto on line 100 of course)?

Comment: My appleIIgs runs the above code in 3.9 and 4.7 seconds respectively - hand timed, no TIME function :(  So, this seems to match the PET behavior, also when I change the line numbers to match your 2nd version, I get a similar speedup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PET basic v2 only starts scanning from the current line if the high byte of the goto line number is greater than the high byte of the current line number. Otherwise it starts at the beginning of the program. What happens if you renumber lines 110 up so that they start from 310 (and the goto on line 100 of course)?

Comment: If it is just the high byte, could it not be the case that the line is behind it? For instance, if line 0410 branches to 0400, would this not cause the search to fail?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz These have equal high bytes, so the search would start at the beginning of the program. Note that the high byte must be strictly greater for the optimization to kick in.

Answer (score 10):

Further to WimC's explanation, here's perhaps the worst-case example that's possible on an 8K PET 2001.

This code runs in 2.2 seconds:

```
10 REM AA
  ... 762 MORE LINES LIKE THIS ...
7640 REM AA
7650 T=TI
7660 FOR I=1 TO 1000
7670 GOTO 7680
7680 NEXT I
7690 PRINT(TI-T)/60
```

while this code, with one line fewer, takes over **45** seconds:

```
10 REM AA
  ... 761 MORE LINES LIKE THIS ...
7630 REM AA
7640 T=TI
7650 FOR I=1 TO 1000
7660 GOTO 7670
7670 NEXT I
7680 PRINT(TI-T)/60
```

The issue is clearer if the line numbers are shown in hex:

```
7670 GOTO 7680  →  $1DF6 GOTO $1E00 : fast, as $1E > $1D
7660 GOTO 7670  →  $1DEC GOTO $1DF6 : slow, as $1D = $1D
```

The fast code only has to search for the next line, while the slow code (due to the bug) has to search through > 750 lines from the start of the program to find the target line.

Comment: Wow, that seems like a rather obvious thing to fix at some point.

Comment: Yes, they had by the time the VIC-20 was released.

Comment: I assume they test the first 8 bits for >, then =, and then only test the lower 8-bits if the second was true?

Comment: no; if the high byte wasn't greater, it always restarted the search from the first line

Comment: Huh... any idea why? The second test would only occur if the first failed, so it would only be a couple of cycles done rarely. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand "the bug"?

Comment: they only did one test, and it wasn't a very good one. More often than not it caused a program slowdown. Yes, they should have compared 16-bit addresses, but they didn't.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Part of it may be the legacy of the 8080 and 6800 versions from which the 6502 version was derived. Not only did the 8080 and 6800 no doubt use their 16-bit compares, but the 6502 version was possibly under a fair amount of space pressure before they finally gave up on making ["BASIC M6502 8K v1.1"](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24614/7208) actually fit in 8K instead of 9K.

Answer (score 7):

If memory serves, the BASIC in the C64 and VIC-20 checks whether a GOTO line number is greater than or equal to the present line number and will scan from the start of the current line if so, and otherwise start from the beginning of the program.  I wouldn't be surprised if the PET BASIC is always starting from the start of the program.  It looks like the code is taking about 720 extra cycles per goto, to scan 11 lines, so about 65 cycles/line.  It's too bad 6502 versions of MS-BASIC didn't store the length of each line at the start, rather than an address link, since that would have saved a byte per line, reduced scanning time (to about 26 cycles/line), and eliminated the need to fix up line links when code gets relocated.

Answer (score 1):

It is more likely counting from the beginning.  In 8bit basic, the line lengths are stored, and to find the beginning of a line, it must, look at each line.

I had the same with the Tandy 100.

Comment: Yup, I'm well aware of that issue: MS BASIC slows way down with lots of lines trying to locate GOTOs. But this wouldn't explain why the PET's GOTO is so much slower than the C64's

Comment: Commodore basic stores pointers to the next line instead of line length

Comment: It doesn't matter in either case.  It still has to access the lines in turn.  One of the indexing programs reads the line length, and creates a position pointer as needed.