# Oddity in MS BASIC line lookup code on the 6502

Tags: microsoft-basic

Does anyone know for sure why MS BASICs on the 6502 compared only the page number when deciding where to look for line numbers on branches? IIRC, it would only "start looking from here" if the target was at least a page higher.

This seems odd, as it means you cannot `THEN` back to your own line and get the quick lookup. This is common for small loops, which would seem like a good target for this code. Any short forward branch will likely fail as well.

I guess you save one compare, but as the line lookup is going to do pretty much exactly that 2-byte compare on *every line*, it seems that there's really no downside (it's like adding one line to the code).

So am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I guess not. Seems like an (premature) optimization, done without checking against code. The only part where I could see this coming is when looking at very early Basic programs with single statement per line and THEN GOT being the norm, as they usually cover longer distance due more line overhead.

Comment: Is it this you're referring to: [Commodore BASIC: why was the PET's GOTO so slow?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17314/commodore-basic-why-was-the-pets-goto-so-slow/17358#17358). If so, it's clearly a bug

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commodore BASIC: why was the PET's GOTO so slow?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17314/commodore-basic-why-was-the-pets-goto-so-slow)  - I think this may really be better suited as part of that other question, shouldn't it? Or, if it really needs to be a question on its on, clearly refference the other question and make clear what the additional knowledge ist that is lookd for.